# jQuery absolute positioned buttons binding

Tags: jquery, css, bind

I have two buttons that were firing functions once clicked on. jQuery was handling them via bind. Once I added position:absolute to the div that was containing those buttons, the binding doesn't work anymore in firefox and chrome, but works in IE (lol).

what could be causing this problem?

Comment: have you tried putting a width and height on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the div is now behind anything else.  Use firebug and use the object identifier to see what comes up when you hover over the button. If it's not the button, then it means the div over top is actually registering the clicks.  Change the Z-order or re-flow your code so the button is on top if this is the case.

Comment: setting z-index worked like a charm.
you were correct, there was another div that was overlaying the buttons div.